# check if firewall is on without any package like iptables

Tags: linux, firewall

On Linux, is there any command/logfile to confirm that the firewall is enabled without the use of the iptables or any such package that needs to be installed.

I just want to know if there is a default logfile/command for linux that can tell me if firewall is enabled or present? For example, use of netfilter?

Thanks

Comment: Without the command-line iptables stuff, there'd be no practical way to load up rules anyways.

Comment: Note that simply loading e.g. `ip6_tables` causes the firewall to become "active" (as in, its code is executed) even if you do not have any rules that do anything for you.

Answer (score 2):

That's easy; if you don't have iptables installed, you don't have the tools required to set up netfilter, so I'm pretty sure it can't be active.

That said, you could try looking under `/proc/sys/net/netfilter` or `/proc/net/netfilter` - although I don't see how you can get much useful information out of the conntrack state that's exposed there.